# How can I set multiple items background color in a ListView?

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` with a about 20 items. I want the first, third and tenth item to have a black background. I have tried using

```
listView.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Inside `onCreate`, but the app crashed when I ran it. After testing all sorts I eventually created a countdown timer which counts down from 50 milliseconds and runs the code `onFinish`. But now I am having problems with the items recycling. I've tried setting the background color for the items that are recycled back to default, but when I do this the app crashes.
I have looked around for a solution but all I can find are some that use selections but I need 3 items to have a black background.

Is there no simple way to set the background color of items without being recycled? They don't need to be changed at run time or anything like that.

Comment: In adapter class when a view is created ...use that position variable to set the color to the item or background color whatever you want.

Comment: In what adapter class? Sorry, I'm new to android and don't know what you mean.

Comment: yeah in your adapter class...you have a method use the position variable ...and create a if or switch accordingly...

Comment: getView() method of the list view wait i will just paste the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: According to your question

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(ListActivity.this , R.layout.custom_list , items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <String>{

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);
        }
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ll);
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        if (position == 1) {
            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        if (position == 3) {
            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        if (position == 10) {
            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        tv.setText(items.get(position));

        return v;
    }

}
```

and just to be sure The itemlistrow.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

i hopw it helps you now.

Comment: Thanks, what do I use for the <Item>?
I'm trying to set the adapter like this:

    adapter = new android.widget.ListAdapter<Item>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I've tried it, but I don't think I'm using it properly. Like above I said <Item> gives an error, but I also don't know what to replace R.id.itemlistrow with.

Comment: I have got it running now, but the black backgrounds keep recycling when I scroll down and the items from my array aren't appearing in the list.

Comment: Item is a custom class for that arrayList.

Comment: what is the type of items you are passing? is it an array??

Comment: Its a String array.

Comment: okay okay you can use arrayList of string type and change Item with String it will work fine ..or you can chnage List to string in adapter. I will upload the code as soon as i reach home.

Comment: if you are gettin any error do tell. the above code works in mine. and do upvote if you fell it solves your query.

Comment: I'll give it a try when I get home,  thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'm getting an error here:

    adapter = new ListAdapter(ListActivity.this, R.layout.custom_list , items);

the "ListActivity.this" is underlined in red with this error:
https://imgur.com/a/PfKB1

Comment: I now changed the "String[] items" to "java.util.ArrayList<String> items", so that it matches my item array but now I have two problems: First problem is that the listview isn't populated with any of the text I have in the array list, and the second problem is when I scroll up and down the background color changes to different items. 

This is the result after scrolling down and up twice:
https://imgur.com/a/CNtFy

Comment: i have compiled the code with respect to your code. dont change it to ArrayList it was according to array. and if you want to change it to arrayList use arraylist method of get() to retrieve and also as i initialised linearlayout ...initialise t3xtview amd set that textview as your arraylist items. send me your string array ...i will edit the code

Comment: I updated the question with my entire activities code.

Comment: Yes! The black parts are meant to be for the dates, but thats easy to change myself.

Comment: do upvote and mark as correct if you feel like @Fn20

Comment: I will do. It works now, but when I scroll down and up the black background changes to different items.

Comment: A friendly Advice... the concept you are using is kinda not appropriate but you are a beginner you can but in actual you must create a class that stores these info and then a arrayList of that class type and give a attribute of whether its date or not so that you can have black background in this way you will save your time in if statement and also you should consider using expandable list ...that will expand the date to show the various courses below it...

Comment: The view is created again and again that's why the black is the problem. Consider doing the above said or recycle the view.  If you want then dont use if with position use it with String.. like if(items.get(position).equals("History")){//your code of black color}

Comment: Its not most efficient way to do it but as you said you are a beginner you can try it and make it work then work your ladder up to achieve efficiency because efficient apps are good. try using RecyclerView for efficiency also read above 3 comments for all other answers

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried setting the other items color to white and now they don't seem to swap with eachother.